# How to fix "client" not defined

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So i coded a discord bot that when execute the command /sub-yt.js it shows a button that when triggered it shows a modal but when i do the following command: npm run test, i get this:

```
PS C:\Users\itstr\Documents\discord bot> npm run test

> discord-bot@1.0.0 test
> node .

Command: button has passed through the handler
Command: embed has passed through the handler
Command: modal has passed through the handler
Command: ping has passed through the handler
Started refreshing application (/) commands.
C:\Users\itstr\Documents\discord bot\src\components\buttons\sub-yt.js:25
client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
^

ReferenceError: client is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\itstr\Documents\discord bot\src\components\buttons\sub-yt.js:25:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1257:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1311:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:962:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1139:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:121:18)
    at client.handleComponents (C:\Users\itstr\Documents\discord bot\src\functions\handler\handleComponents.js:14:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\itstr\Documents\discord bot\src\bot.js:20:8)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1257:14)

Node.js v20.3.1
```

It seems that in the specific code line 25: `client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {` client is not defined, here's the full code of sub-yt.js

```
module.exports = {
    data: {
        name: 'sub-yt'
    },
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        await interaction.reply({
            content: 'Please wait...',
            components: [
                {
                    type: 'ACTION_ROW',
                    components: [
                        {
                            type: 'BUTTON',
                            style: 'PRIMARY',
                            customId: 'open-modal',
                            label: 'Open Modal'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });
    }
};
// Event listener for button click
client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
    if (interaction.isButton()) {
        if (interaction.customId === 'open-modal') {
            // Execute the modal.js code here
            // Example: require('./modal.js').execute(interaction, client);
            await interaction.reply({
                content: 'Executing modal...',
                ephemeral: true
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, it's not defined. Why do you want to add a new event listener there?

Comment: No i just don't know how to define "client"

Comment: It's your code, you should know how to define it. I guess that you wanted to use it inside `execute` function instead of globally

Comment: Each module is its own independent scope and has its own variables.  If you want to use the `client` variable, then you have to either export it from some other module and import it into this module or put the code that uses it into a function that is called by some code that passes it the `client` variable.  Those are you two preferred choices.  It could also be made a global by some other module, but that is not considered good design in the modular world of either nodejs or ESM modules (you should not be defining any globals).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `client` on a file used for your command. Since Node.js wouldn't know what's "client". Try copying that part (client.on('.....') untill the end of the file to your main project file. Probably named `index.js`